# Link XML files to ToolStripLabels in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to create a form menu that uses ToolStripLabels and ToolStripMenuItems. I want to feed the information as well as structure from an XML file so that when I update the XML file the menu is updated dynamically. 
I have started coding it however am struggling to find the best way to map the data and consequently have the right structures in the menu to follow the XML structures.

For example (for the sake of simplicity), my XML file could be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Menu1>
  <subMenu1>
    <subSubMenu1>1</subSubMenu1>
  </subMenu1>
</Menu1>
```

and I would like to have Menu1 mapped in ToolStripLabel1, subMenu in ToolStripMenu1, and subSubMenu1 in ToolStripMenuItem1 -- and the "1" within a ToolStripTextBox.

Comment: Do you need to structure to change during runtime? Or is it ok to change only after the xml changes *and* the program is restarted / form is reloaded?

Comment: `to have Menu1 mapped in ToolStripLabel1` what does this mean? How do you map a hierarchical object to a single Label? Menu1 has child objects, but a Label does not. Can you perhaps build your desired menu in the designer and provide a screenshot and a clearer description?

Comment: Maybe add more children to the xml as well. The schema of Xml with single elements is ambiguous, particularly whether a single child node is potentially one of many, or always just a single node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your XML structure a bit, because it's a little confusing. Instead of putting the `1` identifier in the element name, put it in an attribute. I guess it's supposed to be the menu text so I gave them some structural names.

Well here is some XML I came up with

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Menu>
  <MenuItem Text="SubMenu1">
    <MenuItem Text="SubSubMenu1" TextBox="abc"/>
    <MenuItem Text="SubSubMenu2">
      <MenuItem Text="SubSubSubMenu1" TextBox="def">
        <MenuItem Text="SubSubSubSubMenu1"/>
        <MenuItem Text="SubSubSubSubMenu2"/>
        <MenuItem Text="SubSubSubSubMenu3" TextBox="ghi"/>
        <MenuItem Text="SubSubSubSubMenu4"/>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem Text="SubSubSubMenu2"/>
    </MenuItem>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem Text="SubMenu2">
    <MenuItem Text="SubSubMenu1"/>
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

These are classes which can be used to deserialize from the XML file and hold the state

```vb
<XmlRoot>
Public Class Menu
    <XmlElement("MenuItem")>
    Public MenuItems As List(Of MenuItem)
End Class

Public Class MenuItem
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Text As String
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public TextBox As String
    <XmlElement("MenuItem")>
    Public MenuItems As List(Of MenuItem)
    Public Function CreateToolStripMenuItem(isSubMenu As Boolean) As ToolStripMenuItem
        Dim tsmi = New ToolStripMenuItem(Me.Text)
        If isSubMenu Then AddHandler tsmi.Click, Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) MessageBox.Show($"You clicked {DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Text}")
        If Me.TextBox <> "" Then
            Dim tb = New ToolStripTextBox() With {.Text = Me.TextBox}
            'tb.ReadOnly = True
            tsmi.DropDownItems.Add(tb)
        End If
        If Me.MenuItems.Any Then
            For Each mi In Me.MenuItems
                tsmi.DropDownItems.Add(mi.CreateToolStripMenuItem(True))
            Next
        End If
        Return tsmi
    End Function
End Class
```

And some test code. All you need is an empty form with this code to test it, and an XML file which can be loaded "filename.xml"

```vb
Option Strict On

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        loadMenus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub loadMenus()
        Dim s = New XmlSerializer(GetType(Menu))
        Dim menu As Menu
        Using sr = New StreamReader("filename.xml")
            menu = CType(s.Deserialize(sr), Menu)
        End Using
        Dim ms = New MenuStrip()
        For Each item In menu.MenuItems
            ms.Items.Add(item.CreateToolStripMenuItem(False))
        Next
        ms.Visible = True
        Me.Controls.Add(ms)
    End Sub

End Class
```

It uses recursion so there is only one Menu class in both the XML and .NET and you can have any level of menu depth.

There is support for adding click event handlers in the code. Up to you to use it or not.

Comment: This is excellent, thanks so much!! I need a bit more of advise regarding the attribute issue that you mentioned though. The menus (and more specifically the submenus) are actually linked parameters which would eventually end on a numerical entry (hence the '1' I used initially), for a quantity characteristic. Can you please advise how I can add a textbox or entry record that can also be tracked in the same manner as you displayed for menus/submenus?

Comment: I deleted the previous question since I read now your post well--- you have already accounted with recursion the issue about deeper levels-- thanks. Is there a way to output a string of all of the items involved in a chain (up until the time I create an entry -- like the '1' above)? Sorry to keep blasting you with requests, but is there a way of determining particular actions whenever particular submenus are clicked? thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Cevillasenor I added support for textboxes. I hope it helps

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way of clicking on a particular item that I can MsgBox the parent nodes  related to that item??

Comment: how do you `MsgBox parent nodes`?

Comment: I meant to say if there is a way of using the clicking capability that you added so that when I click on a particular item I can get the tracing of the higher level items on top of that one. do you think this is possible to do? thanks for all your help BTW!